# Dynamic routes with different functions in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have loads of `router.get` functions in my code which I think, could be reduced to a single switch-case function. Here is what I have tried:

```
function handlerA(req, res) {}

function handlerB(req, res) {}

var routes = {
    '/url-one': handlerA,
    '/url-two': handlerB
}

router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    var url = req.url;

    if (routes[url]) {
        routes[url](req, res);
    }
});
```

This works but also, significantly slows my application. Is there any other solution which would not hit the performance of my app?

Thanks

Comment: What do you gain by having a single switch case? Why not just do it parametrized as express supports?

Comment: Also, where do you see a performance hit? Finally, I assume yu mean `'/url-one':handlerA` and not to immediately execute `handlerA()`. Similarly for `routes.url` and `routes[url]`

Comment: My program runs a lot slower than it does with multiple router.get() functions. I don't know the reason for this.

Comment: How are you measuring slower? If you can put a gist or github branch up, it would be interesting to clone it and see.

Comment: Either way, why do you not want to use the default `router.get()`?

Comment: I have approximately 10 router.get() functions in my file and I thought this does not respect the DRY contract.

Comment: When I have more than a few routes, I usually do `router.get()` in my main server file (make all routes visible in one place), and then require other files that `export` a `function(req,res,next)`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to use `router.get` functions? I would guess `express.js` is internally performing the same logic that you are doing anyway. You are just replacing `get` functions with handlers.

If you are using similar logic between multiple routes, that may be worth abstracting.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with a setup like this:

```
app.js
routes.js
api/
  user/
    index.js
    user.controller.js
    user.model.js
  image/
    index.js
    image.controller.js
    image.model.js
```

**/api/user/index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./user.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.post('/', controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

**/api/user/user.controller.js:**

```
var User = require('./user.model');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  // Show list of users
};

exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
  // Create user
};
```

**/routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  // Insert routes below
  app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));
  app.use('/api/images', require('./api/image'));

  // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
   .get(errors[404]);

  // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
  app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });
};
```

And lastly, the **/app.js:**

```
// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/environment');

// Connect to database
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

// Populate DB with sample data
if(config.seedDB) { require('./config/seed'); }

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Start server
server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Most of this is directly from the Yeoman Generator [Angular-Fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) and it has a *really* nice setup!